# Turn off console logging for Hydra when using Pytorch Lightning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch-lightning, fb-hydra

Is there a way to turn off console logging for Hydra, but keep file logging? I am encountering a problem where Hydra is duplicating all my console prints. These prints are handled by Pytorch Lightning and I want them to stay like that. However, I am fine with hydra logging them to a file (once per print), but I do not want to see my prints twice in the console.

Comment: I tried using hydra/job_logging=disabled and hydra/hydra_logging=disabled when calling my python script but this also disabled some of the Pytorch Lightning logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled a bit with the hydra documentation which is why I wanted to write a detailed explanation here so that other people can have it easy. In order to be able to use the answer proposed by @j_hu, i.e.:

```
hydra/job_logging=none
hydra/hydra_logging=none
```

with hydra 1.0 (which is the stable version at the time I am writing this answer) you need to first:

1. Create a directory called hydra within your config directory.
2. Create two subdirectories: job_logging and hydra_logging.
3. Create two none.yaml files in both of those directories as described below.

```
# @package _group_
version: 1
root: null
disable_existing_loggers: false
```

After this is done, you can use the `none.yaml` configuration to either override the logging via the command line:

`python main.py hydra/job_logging=none hydra/hydra_logging=none`

or via the `config.yaml` file:

```
defaults:
  - hydra/hydra_logging: none
  - hydra/job_logging: none
```

Comment: Thank you! 
The `none` option is available out of the box in Hydra 1.1 but not in Hydra 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have a similar issue here https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1012

Have you tried setting

```
hydra/job_logging=none
hydra/hydra_logging=none
```

as suggested in the issue and see if works better for you?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer it worked. As I struggled a bit with the documentation I will post an additional answer with a detailed explanation on what you need to do with Hydra 1.0 to disable the logging.